# Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, mapstruct

While trying to map my domain objects I get the following StackOverflowError exception. I've tried to ignore the properties causing circular dependencies to no avail.

At the center of my domain model is the WorkoutSet which has a User and an Exercise.

If I remove the mapping annotation from the WorkoutSetMapper the UserMapperImpl and the ExerciseMapperImpl is generated as expected.

> Error:(15, 1) java: Internal error in the mapping processor:
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError      at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:786)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4652) 
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.supertype(Types.java:2315)    at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1966)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1955)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:786)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:4571)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.asSuper(Types.java:1952)      at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1968)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1955)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:786)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:4571)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.asSuper(Types.java:1952)      at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1975)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1955)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:786)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:4571)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.asSuper(Types.java:1952)      at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1975)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1955)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:786)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:4571)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.asSuper(Types.java:1952)      at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1975)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1955)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:786)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:4571)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.asSuper(Types.java:1952)      at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$4.visitClassType(Types.java:921)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$4.visitClassType(Types.java:844)   at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:786)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:4571)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isSubtype(Types.java:840)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isSubtype(Types.java:804)      at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacTypes.isSubtype(JavacTypes.java:98) 
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.util.workarounds.SpecificCompilerWorkarounds.isSubtype(SpecificCompilerWorkarounds.java:76)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.util.workarounds.TypesDecorator.isSubtype(TypesDecorator.java:68)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.common.Type.isSubType(Type.java:638) 
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.common.Type.isCollection(Type.java:628)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.common.Type.isCollectionOrMap(Type.java:624)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.common.Type.getAlternativeTargetAccessors(Type.java:598)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.common.Type.getPropertyWriteAccessors(Type.java:419)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.source.TargetReference$BuilderFromTargetMapping.getTargetEntries(TargetReference.java:144)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.source.TargetReference$BuilderFromTargetMapping.build(TargetReference.java:120)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.source.Mapping.init(Mapping.java:227) 
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.source.SourceMethod$Builder.build(SourceMethod.java:207)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MethodRetrievalProcessor.getMethodRequiringImplementation(MethodRetrievalProcessor.java:257)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MethodRetrievalProcessor.getMethod(MethodRetrievalProcessor.java:193)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MethodRetrievalProcessor.retrieveMethods(MethodRetrievalProcessor.java:148)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MethodRetrievalProcessor.retrieveMethods(MethodRetrievalProcessor.java:163)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MethodRetrievalProcessor.retrieveMethods(MethodRetrievalProcessor.java:163)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MethodRetrievalProcessor.retrieveMethods(MethodRetrievalProcessor.java:163)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MethodRetrievalProcessor.retrieveMethods(MethodRetrievalProcessor.java:163)
>     at
>   org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MethodRetrievalProcessor.retrieveMethods
>   ...

My domain classes are as follows

```
            @Entity
            public class User implements FirstClassDomainObject {
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private long id;
                private String name;
                private String email;
            ...

            @Entity
            public class Exercise implements FirstClassDomainObject {
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private long id;
                private String name;
                private String description;
            ...

            @Entity
            public class WorkoutSet implements FirstClassDomainObject {
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private long id;
                private int repetition;
                private double wight;
                private LocalDateTime timestamp;
                @ManyToOne
                private Exercise exercise;
                @ManyToOne
                private User user;
            ...
```

My DTO classes are as follows

```
            public class UserResource implements ResourceObject {
                private Long id;
                private String name;
                private String email;
            ...

            public class ExerciseResource implements ResourceObject {
                private String name;
                private String description;
            ...

            public class WorkoutSetResource implements ResourceObject {
                private int repetition;
                private double wight;
                @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
                private LocalDateTime timestamp;
                private ExerciseResource exercise;
                private UserResource user;
            ...
```

My mapper interfaces are as follows

```
            @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
            interface UserMapper extends ClassMapper<User, UserResource> {
                @Override
                default List<Class<?>> getSupportedClasses() {
                    return Lists.newArrayList(User.class, UserResource.class);
                }
            }


            @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
            interface ExerciseMapper extends ClassMapper<Exercise, ExerciseResource> {
                @Override
                default List<Class<?>> getSupportedClasses() {
                    return Lists.newArrayList(Exercise.class, ExerciseResource.class);
                }
            }

            @Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UserMapper.class, WorkoutSetMapper.class})
            interface WorkoutSetMapper extends ClassMapper<WorkoutSet, WorkoutSetResource> {
                @Override
                default List<Class<?>> getSupportedClasses() {
                    return Lists.newArrayList(WorkoutSet.class, WorkoutSetResource.class);
                }
            }
```

The ClassMapper is defined as follows

```
            public interface ClassMapper<D extends DomainObject, R extends ResourceObject> {
                R map(D domainObject);
                D map(R resourceObject);
                List<Class<?>> getSupportedClasses();
            }
```

I've left out getter and setter methods to avoid a wall of text but the entire code base can be found here https://github.com/tonsV2/Lift-Log-Backend.
Any clue about what I've done wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have a circular reference in your objects

Comment: Yeah, but how do I prevent mapstruct from following them?

Comment: I don't know. I just don't think you should have a User hold a set of workouts, which, in turn, point back to the user that has them. Similar for exercises.

Comment: The problem persists evne if I remove the @OneToMany from both User and Exercise. But you are right. I've updated the question.

Comment: I think it'd be clearer if you could describe your domain model. Or even create an ER diagram, if you're comfortable with that

Comment: I've added a short comment at the beginning of the post. I hope that clarifies it a bit. I suspected the circular references to be the cause of this. But now that I've removed them I'm totally clueless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the error! I've set the WorkoutSetMapper to use itself.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UserMapper.class, WorkoutsetMapper.class})
interface WorkoutSetMapper extends ClassMapper<WorkoutSet, WorkoutSetResource> {
```

While I should have had

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UserMapper.class, ExerciseMapper.class})
interface WorkoutSetMapper extends ClassMapper<WorkoutSet, WorkoutSetResource> {
```